# Loss of a parameter in Deserialization with Json.NewSofton c # Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms, deserialization

I have a problem with json deserialization with json newtonsoft. He can not deserialize all object parameters when calling the API.
Below is all my code.
As you can see with postapi the bees responding correctly all the parameters, it is when deserialize who loses a parameter.

newtonsoft json decode:

```
var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                var xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
                String indexof = xml.Substring(76, xml.Length - 85);

                USR_User_ReturnList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OBJ_User>>(indexof);
```

object class:

```
public class OBJ_User
    {
        public int DLR_Id { get; set; }
        public string DLR_Username { get; set; }
        public string DLR_Password_Hash { get; set; }
        public object DLR_Nome { get; set; }
        public string DLR_Cognome { get; set; }
        public int DLR_Tipo { get; set; }
        public string DLR_Azienda { get; set; }
        public object DLR_Telefono { get; set; }
        public object DLR_Email { get; set; }
        public int DLR_Abilitato { get; set; }
        public object DLR_Time_Zone { get; set; }
        public object DLR_Country { get; set; }
        public string DLR_Culture { get; set; }
        public object DLR_Email1 { get; set; }
        public object DLR_MCC_Modello_Alias { get; set; }
        public object DLR_Anagrafica { get; set; }
        public object DLR_Firma { get; set; }
        public bool IsFIMAP { get; set; }
        public bool IsSTANDARD { get; set; }
        public bool IsDealerOrFimap { get; set; }
        public object DLR_Tipo_Esteso { get; set; }
        public object DLR_Abilitato_Esteso { get; set; }
    }
```

indexof json from StreamReader, from code:

```
[{"DLR_Id":15,"DLR_Username":"dealer02","DLR_Password_Hash":"P4ssw0rd2","DLR_Nome":null,"DLR_Cognome":"Rossi2","DLR_Tipo":0,"DLR_Azienda":"AziendaRossi2","DLR_Telefono":null,"DLR_Email":null,"DLR_Abilitato":1,"DLR_Time_Zone":null,"DLR_Country":null,"DLR_Culture":"","DLR_Email1":null,"DLR_MCC_Modello_Alias":null,"DLR_Anagrafica":null,"DLR_Firma":null,"IsFIMAP":false,"IsSTANDARD":false,"IsDealerOrFimap":true,"DLR_Tipo_Esteso":null,"DLR_Abilitato_Esteso":null}]
```

indexof from postman (right response), from api:

```
[{"DLR_Id":15,"DLR_Username":"dealer02","DLR_Password_Hash":"P4ssw0rd2","DLR_Nome":null,"DLR_Cognome":"Rossi2","DLR_Tipo":0,"DLR_Azienda":"AziendaRossi2","DLR_Telefono":null,"DLR_Email":null,"DLR_Abilitato":1,"DLR_Time_Zone":null,"DLR_Country":null,"DLR_Culture":"","DLR_Email1":null,"DLR_MCC_Modello_Alias":null,"DLR_Anagrafica":null,"DLR_Firma":null,"IsFIMAP":false,"IsSTANDARD":false,"IsDealerOrFimap":true,"DLR_Tipo_Esteso":null,"DLR_Abilitato_Esteso":null}]
```

Lost this parameter: **IsDealerOrFimap**

i have tested json with http://json.parser.online.fr/ and works, the conversion is right, but from code i lost one IsDealerOrFimap parameter.

The list is properly riempieta me, but all the items on the list do not have the IsDealerOrFimap parameter, loses it ... why?

unfortunately it takes me all parameters except one (**IsDealerOfFimap**), and can not understand why ... does anyone have any solution?

[image]

***solution***
i tryed format android device and now works correctly. mistery!

Comment: what do you mean by 'lost this parameter' if it's in both responses?

Comment: and it is correctly deserialized with your code

Comment: I mean that when I convert from json in C # list, I get all deserialized objects properly, but does not fill me IsDealerOrFimap parameter, so that the debugging tells me nonexistent parameter in.

Comment: *String indexof = xml.Substring(76, xml.Length - 85);* Take the XML, truncate it a bit, now it's JSON, oh hey look it's not working

Comment: if i take json you have posted and deserialize it exact as you have done, i see this property set to true

Comment: yes is right, but after deserialization i lost the IsDealerOrFimap parameter in all objects list.

Comment: Please explain very explicitly what you see happening. _"does not fill me IsDealerOrFimap parameter, so that the debugging tells me nonexistent parameter in"_ is not clear.

Comment: I seem to have been clear, we tried again, maybe my English will not let me be clear .: I read a json from an API, which comes to me properly, but when deserializzo in a list, I have all parameters except object one: IsDealerOrFimap, I do not find myself in this parameter list.

Comment: What do you mean by _"I do not find myself in this parameter list"_? Does the class you're deserializing into not have that property?

Comment: I updated the question, putting the list that I am in debug, as you can see the objects do not have the IsDealerOrFimap parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If a JSON object contains fields that can't be mapped to properties in the destination class, those fields are silently ignored.

The class you're deserializing your response into (`Fimap.Models.DLR_User`) simply does not have a `IsDealerOrFimap` property that the class you're serializing from has (`OBJ_User`).

Comment: What you sayng, the IsDealerOrFimap is in the class.

Comment: No, it is not. Otherwise IntelliSense would show you the property. The class you're deserializing into is different from the class you're serializing from.

Comment: The class that I am using has it the object, in fact my question is because I lost ... why I lose the parameter?

Comment: If I had to guess, the class is in two different assemblies/namespaces. One doesn't have the property. E.g. a WCF generated proxy, and the proxy hasn't been updated recently.

Comment: OBJ_User and DLR_User have parameter IsDealerOrFimap

Comment: Put your caret on the `_` in `List<OBJ_User>` and push F12.

Comment: @Mr.Developer no, the one you show a screenshot of **doesn't**. Find its definition from the context of your screenshot (F12) and you'll see. Perhaps you're referencing an older version of a library, or you haven't update a Service Reference or whatever.

Comment: I think I understand why, visual studio still refers to the class that I deleted. How does one exist DLR_User the same that does not exist in the project? No way to do a refresh? the intellisense sees me again ... strange. and the new one does not see me or OBJ_User

Comment: @Mr.Developer I think you need to clean and rebuild the solution.